# Fork repository on github through GitHub REST API

Tags: rest, ecmascript-6, async-await, fetch, github-api

How could I make request through GitHub REST API? I have id, generated secret and toket with access to repository, but HOW to make request (correct url or so on) to Fork selected repository?

What I did:

```
const forkRepository = await fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/dd/controlp5/forks", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 2733364296c2b40e2c4088cade1ffc9cc758dbf8,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        return forkRepository;
```

And I took this

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://api.github.com/repos/dd/controlp5/forks", redirected: false, status: 401, ok: false, …}
body: ReadableStream
locked: (...)
__proto__: Object
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers
__proto__: Headers
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
type: "cors"
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/dd/controlp5/forks"
__proto__: Response
```

And the last what i need understand, what token I need to use and how could I take it? Because my acces token doesn't work to fork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI to fork a repository:

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/forks
```

`:owner` replaces the owner and `:repo` the Repository name.

For example, here's a repository forking `germanysources/FOSSwareSearch`:

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/germanysources/FOSSwareSearch/forks
```

The github documentation can be found at:
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/

Comment: Thanks for answer, I edited my request and I understood how to make request: POST type to URI as you signed, but I took 401 error as I noted in my start post

Comment: As mentioned in https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication the access token can be a oauth token. You can create this oauth token in your profile Tab Settings->Developer Settings->Personal Access Token. I wouldn't recommend to post the access token in the code snippet. Everbody can see and use it.

Comment: I generated this token, but it doesn't help me in request, I took 401 error insteed 202 success answer... Maybe I need to generate it with some another params... And what is yot suggestions in case of non post any Auth tokents and etc in application?

Comment: I meant replace the token in your code snippet on stackoverflow. It's  visible to everybody in the internet. On the documentation you can see the header is "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" The keyword token is missing in your code and make sure the token can access repositories

Comment: Don't worry about token above, it has changed. F*c 4 days I tried to solve that and the reason was only in one KEYWORD?!!! That's fail, I stop dev practice and gonna dancing... Thanks a lot for the help, beauty wife and children to you, thanks one more time.